# how to create a plugin system in php?

Tags: php, wordpress, web-applications, plugins

I am looking for way to build a plugin system similar to that found in various famous CMSs like Joomla and Wordpress.

I am looking for a PHP base plugin system to get started with easily and that which is not hard to understand and implement/integrate.

Here is what I need is more details:
We have built a business web app. In this web app our clients is asking us to add facility of extending it using a plugin based system so that other developers can develop new features and extend the app.

The system should allow the developer a way to build features/functionality in one or more than one files and zip then and install them. On installation the features programmed should automatically appear in the core application.

The plugin should have both back end and front end interface support also.

If the feature is not required then one has only to remove the plugin and the features should go away!

I have searched the web for this and have also tired to study WordPress's Plugin system to see if I can integrate similar functionality but unfortunately it is way too complex for me to understand let along try to implement it!

TIA

Yogi Yang

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or __find a tool__, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: Agreed off-topic, but to answer the question such a system doesn't really exist. What you are looking for is a PHP developer framework, try codeigniter or something like that.

Comment: Build one. This kind of thing isn't usually something you can pluck off the shelf as it usually needs "hooks" or an event handler in your core application code. A basic solution is to implement some hooks in your code and let your plugins attach custom functions to those hooks. Then call them with [`call_user_func()`](http://uk3.php.net/function.call-user-func).

Comment: I am studying phphooks but there are almost no documentation regarding it.

Comment: I also found phplexus it seems interesting for building plugin based systems using it! (http://code.google.com/p/phpplexus/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is too general a question for a site like this. There are many different ways to create a plugin system, and they all have their relative strengths & weaknesses.

For more information on how something like WordPress's API works, read about the [publish-subscribe pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Publish%E2%80%93subscribe_pattern). WordPress has a set of [actions](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference) and [filters](http://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference) that it invokes as it processes a page, and plugins can register their interest in receiving notifications about these events.

Drupal's plugin architecture is similar, but it relies on functions having a certain name corresponding to the hook they interact with, and Drupal builds an index of what functions a plugin supports when the plugin is activated. This tends to be faster, but less flexible and couples the code & database in ways some of us aren't comfortable with.

But to bring this back to the scope of a general answer, you need a defined set of signals/events your app generates and a way for plugins to register their interest in acting on them (actions) or modifying the default action (filters). Then, you document that API so people can design their code around it. The rest (like unzipping files) are just implementation details.

Comment: Thanks for the pointers. You have got me started. :)